# Invalid leap years are being evaluated as valid

Tags: java

I am using the U Helsinki java course and I've run into a problem with the leap year example.

I'm using operators with if and else and my code seems right, however it returns 1700, 1500 as leap years. The example states that it is a leap year if divisible by 4 and if it is also divisible by 100 and 400.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Type a year: ");        
        int year = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        if ((year % 4 == 0) || ((year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 == 0))){
            System.out.println("The year is a leap year.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The year is not a leap year.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Reimeus *however it returns 1700, 1500 as leap years*. While this is hard to believe because that code won't produce such results, there's no improvement to do. This question could be off topic for both sites: codereview and here, unless the question becomes more clear.

Comment: should it not be if `((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 == 0) && (year % 400 == 0)){` Also, if it's divisible by 400 then it's automatically divisible by 100, is it not?

Comment: This is not suitable for CodeReview, as the code does not work. That site is only for improving already functioning code, not debugging.

Comment: @jbutler483 - Incorrect.  Divisible by 4 is a leap year UNLESS divisible by 100, UNLESS divisible by 400.

Comment: the example is written like so: "A year is a leap year if it is divisible by 4. But if the year is divisible by 100, it is a leap year only when it is also divisible by 400."

Comment: Hint.  Don't try to put it into one long statement.  Use 3 separate `if` statements, in series, setting a `leapYear` boolean.  Not "clever", but "clever" isn't so hot if it doesn't work.

Comment: Another hint:  Your first `||` should be `&&`.

Comment: I havent learned booleans, and am working with operators. Also adjusting the code to what you suggested returns 1604 as a non-leap year.

Also, why use &&? To me it seems its seperating the two checks with ||. Like if divisible by 4 or divisible by 100 and 400 then return true.

Comment: If you don't understand the meaning of `&&` and `||` you're better off using the `boolean`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple leap year logic trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387980/a-simple-leap-year-logic-trouble)

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean isLeapYear = false;
if (year % 4 == 0) {
    isLeapYear = true;
}
if (year % 100 == 0) {
    isLeapYear = false;
}
if (year % 400 == 0) {
    isLeapYear = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The rules for a leap year are simple:

- The year must be divisible by 4 and not by 100 **OR**
- The year must be divisible by 400.

You're not fulfilling this with your `&&` and `||`.

Just do this change:

```
if ( (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
     //^year divisible by 4 and not by 100
     || (year % 400 == 0)
     //  ^ year divisible by 400
   ) {
    //rest of your code...
}
```

By removing comments, the code would be

```
if ( (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0))
     || (year % 400 == 0) ) {
    //rest of your code...
}
```

Since you're a starter, I highly recommend you to split lines in your code in order for you to understand it. Once you get more practice, you will end writing something like this:

```
static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    return ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your 'if' statement to:

```
if(((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 !=0))||(year % 400 == 0))
```

In your current 'if' statement, if first condition is true,if statement will be true, & if it is false,then your statement will be false.The second condition doesnt play any part at all.

Answer (score -2):

1700, 1500 are returning as leap years because the if check is not correct .

The correct check is `(year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))`

More information about the algorithm can be found here: [Leap Year Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm)

Comment: I tried this earlier. it does not work as well. Still returns 1500 and 1700 etc as leap years.

Comment: This is perfectly correct, if you add `)` at the end.